# Can't use Spinner in android app

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner in my android app and I can get it to show but the sec. I click it, the app crashes and throws :

Unable to add Window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$Wfb@ is not valid: is your activity running?

The layout is simple. I have an activity that has a list and a button to add something to the list. When clicked, the add button open a popup window that displays the spinner, a text box and a button. Everything works fine till I click the spinner .

Now I've searched google for an hour and found these:

[Android - Dynamically Adding values to Spinners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810361/android-dynamically-adding-values-to-spinners)

[BadTokenException Unable to add Window Spinner in PopUpWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229929/badtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-spinner-in-popupwindow)

[Android Spinner Error : android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609519/android-spinner-error-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to)

and more. They all seem to point to the context, however I've tried everything from using "this", to getApplicationContext, to the name of my activity.context and none of it works. I tried using the answer someone provided twice  instead of just setting the contentView to the page and that made things worse (the app crashed with a null pointer exception right away).

Here's the code for the popup window (executed when the "add" button is clicked):

```
public void add_itinerary_clicked(View view)
{
    LayoutInflater i = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = i.inflate(R.layout.itinerary_add_item_page, null);
    popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.showAtLocation(popupView , Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    Spinner airlineChoice = (Spinner) popupView.findViewById(R.id.airlineSpinner);
    Button addBtn= (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.finish_addItinerary);

    String[] list = new String[1];
    list = airlineMap.keySet().toArray(list);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list );
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    airlineChoice.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);


    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish_addItinerary_clicked();
            popup.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm completely at a loss at this point. If it's not the context (I've tried what others have said) then what is it?

Here's the complete error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@40de1700 is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:993)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:899)
    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:603)
    at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:981)
    at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:609)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is this typo in your code? `lsit = airlineMap.keySet().toArray(list);`

Comment: Can you post the exception that is thrown as an edit please?

Comment: Sorry, no that typo has been updated in the question and not in my actual code. The question now reflects whats in my code correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I think you should not be using the application context, but the activity context.
2. Use a dialog and not a popup. It's easier, less code to maintain, and the standard according to Google.
3. I think there needs to be some sort of click listener on the spinner.

Comment: 1. No context I've used has worked(this. activity.this, getBaseContext, ect etc)

2.  I will try that now

3. I added a listener but that doesnt change the error. :(

Thanks though.

Comment: That worked! That is, the dialog worked. But I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Buggie, I have found a work around. I'm using a dialog instead. It works and doesn't throw an error. I'm not sure why this works and a popup window doesn't but here's my code that works:

```
public void add_itinerary_clicked(View view)
{
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itinerary_add_item_page);

    Spinner airlineChoice = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.airlineSpinner);
    Button addBtn= (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.finish_addItinerary);

    String[] list = new String[1];
    list = airlineMap.keySet().toArray(list);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list );
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    airlineChoice.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    airlineChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish_addItinerary_clicked();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might try is using your activity context, rather than your application/base context. This might help the situation.